# How to count occurrence of word (unigram/bigram/trigram) by month?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

I used this script to scrape some data on a website :

```
import re
import json
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import random


root_url = 'https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/www.gammvert.fr'
urls = [ '{root}?page={i}'.format(root=root_url, i=i) for i in range(1,807) ]

comms = []
notes = []
dates = []

for url in urls: 
    results = requests.get(url)

    time.sleep(20)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    commentary = soup.find_all('section', class_='review__content')

    for container in commentary:

        try:
            comm  = container.find('p', class_ = 'review-content__text').text.strip()

        except:
            comm = container.find('a', class_ = 'link link--large link--dark').text.strip()

        comms.append(comm)

        note = container.find('div', class_ = 'star-rating star-rating--medium').find('img')['alt']
        notes.append(note)

        date_tag = container.div.div.find("div", class_="review-content-header__dates")
        date = json.loads(re.search(r"({.*})", str(date_tag)).group(1))["publishedDate"]

        dates.append(date)

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'comms' : comms,
    'notes' : notes,
    'dates' : dates
    })

data['comms'] = data['comms'].str.replace('\n', '')

data['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dates']).dt.date
data['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dates'])


#print(data.head())
data.to_csv('file.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

Here's the kind of data I obtained : [image: database]

It's in french, don't worry about that. :)

And here's the unigram for all the data:

[image: unigram]

The bigram for all the data : [image: bigram]

And finally the trigram from all the data : [image: trigram]

What I would like is obtain the same thing but by month. I think I need some kind of loop with my code I used for the bigram/trigram :

```
def get_top_n_gram(corpus,ngram_range,n=None):
    vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=ngram_range,stop_words = stop_words).fit(corpus)
    bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
    sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0) 
    words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
    words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return words_freq[:n]

def process(corpus):
    corpus = pd.DataFrame(corpus, columns= ['Text', 'count']).sort_values('count', ascending = True)
    return corpus
```

In order to do the job for all the month at once. But that's kind of hard and I'm having an hard time with it.

In others words, I would like to have those result (unigram/trigram/bigram) by month but my database have comment between 2012 - 2020 so do that manually would be rather tedious so I'm wondering if there is a way to do a loop or something.

Any ideas ?

I hope I'm clear, if not, just tell me :)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you update your question to be more specific about what is making it hard to do the whole month? Are you unsure how to map the dates onto months, are you having unsure how to group your dataframe by month and apply your function to it, are you running out of resources (memory, time) when trying to run it with more data, or something else entirely? It may also help for you to update your question with an example of how you expect the output to look.

Comment: would it maybe help to generate a new column which extracts the month from dates and then use either pandas `groupby` or selecting subsets by `df[df['month']==i_month]`? Afterwards you simply pass one df per month to the evaluation you are already doing now

Comment: It would be quite tedious to pass the evaluation for each month, the database had 8 years in it.

Comment: I edited my post. I hope I'm more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have three problems - extracting a month in your dataframe, running your function for a single month and combining the results of individual months together.

```
top_n = 50
# Setting the month
data['month'] = data.dates.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

# Looping through all months and ngrams ranges
dataframes = list()
for month in data.month.unique():
    month_corpus = data.loc[data.month == month].comms
    for ngram_range in range(1,4):
        top_ngrams = get_top_n_gram(month_corpus, ngram_range=ngram_range, n=top_n)
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(top_ngrams, columns=['word', 'word_count'])
        df['month'] = month
        df['ngram_range'] = ngram_range
        dataframes.append(df)
 # Compiling the results at the end
 result_df = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try that and keep you in touch :)

Comment: That's seems to work, just `data.month().unique()` , `it's data.month.unique()` I think.